# Basic Question on SourceTree functionality: generic repository support?

Tags: git, client, atlassian-sourcetree

I installed Sourcetree version 3.4.16 for Windows (the latest at the moment)

Cannot figure out if it supports connecting to remote repos that are NOT Github, Bitbuket, or other popular repo servers.  Has anyone had any luck using this git client with generic git repositories? (Intend to use ssh keys, but not even at that stage of configuration, apparently).

Do I have to use GitHub, BitBucket, and similar, with SourceTree? Or can one use any git remote server, including "no name" ones?

The following may or not be relevant to the above question:

Was mildly shocked to discover the windows version is apparently missing a lot of the features demo-ed in online tutorials, which are apparently demoing the Mac version.

The Windows version (3.4.16) seems to be missing several key functions that exit in the Mac version. (Feels like "false advertising" - even if that is a NULL concept in open source)

As an example, the online tutorial demoes the "Clone/New" button, top left (in the button ribbon).  That is missing in the Windows version. Along with several others.

Comment: First of all: You can use any git remote server in Sourcetree, then Sourcetree is a free graphical user interface (GUI) desktop client that simplifies how you interact with Git repositories so that you can fully concentrate on coding. I have no problems e.g. connecting an Azure repository to Sourcetree. The thing about the missing functionality doesn't mean anything to me. Can you add a screenshot to the question showing where the problems occure?